# PHPUnit. Как протестировать конструктор?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Есть класс, который при создании экземпляра принимает URL, проверяет его на доступность и если все окей - пишет в свойство. Если URL отдает ошибку, то экземпляр не создается.

```
class UrlValidator {
    private $url;

    function __construct($url){
        $this->checkUrl($url);
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    private function checkUrl($url){
        $urlHeaders = get_headers($url);
        if ($urlHeaders[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
            throw new Exception("Url is incorrect.");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function getUrl(){
        echo $this->url;
    }
}

$a = new UrlValidator('https://www.paperplane.io/404');
$a -> getUrl();
```

Подскажите, как подступиться к тестированию этого класса. Как тестировать конструктор? Невалидный URL - я указал в коде. Валидный, для теста, можно поставить `https://www.paperplane.io` Хотелось бы посмотреть непосредственно код теста, а не теорию. Разбираться - так на реальном примере.

Comment: Убедитесь что Вам нужен такой класс, у которого всего один метод. Может более логично использовать функцию или хотя бы класс помощник (helper, со статическими методами)? Вам к сожалению не кто не может подсказать. Так как мы не знаем чего должен делать Ваш класс (именно мелочи). А так обварачивайте в try и ловите exception.
`try {
    $url = new UrlValidator('...');
} catch (Exception $e) {
     // тут должна быть проверка по коду exception-а
}`

Comment: Это упрощенная часть библиотеки. Целиком она содержит добрый десяток методов и столько же свойств. Мне просто интересен синтаксис тестирования конструктора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делать конструктор тяжеловесным — это дурная практика. По-хорошему конструктор должен просто сохранять переданные значения, а работа должна происходить в каких-нибудь методах, которые вызываются отдельно.

Непонятно, почему тестирование конструктора вызывает у вас вопросы. Возможно, одну порочную практику — долго выполняющийся конструктор — вы скрестили с другой порочной практикой — создание всех объектов в общем инициализаторе для всех тестов класса.

Бросать базовый `Exception` — это тоже порочная практика.

А прибивать гвоздями проверку ошибки HTTP к версии HTTP и конкретному коду HTTP — это просто баг. По-хорошему надо полноценно разбирать строчку и убеждаться, что код ответа вас устраивает (вряд ли вас устроит хоть какой-то ответ 4** или 5**).

Что касается кода, то в случае использования PHPUnit у вас есть возможность воспользоваться методом `setExpectedException` или коментарием `@expectedException`. Но и это многими считается порочной практикой, так как этот способ не позволяет убедиться, что исключение брошено именно там, где вы ожидали. По-хорошему надо не лениться писать
`init() try { operation() } catch (MyException e) { assertFoo(e ...) } fail()`
или
`init() try { operation() fail() } catch (MyException e) { assertFoo(e ...) }`.

Comment: Спасибо за советы по реализации класса. Если следовать им и вынести весь функционал в отдельно вызываемые методы, то покрытие тестами конструктора становится ненужным. С одной стороны вопрос решен. Но с другой стороны, чисто в общеобразовательных целях, вопрос покрытия тестом конструктора остается. Как вообще выглядит такой тест? Конструктор покрывается тестами как обычный публичный метод или как? Повторюсь, интересует живой код, потому что сухое перечисление методов тестирования, я и в мануале PHPUnit могу прочитать.

Comment: @qtm почему бы не почитать документацыю, извините не каждому такой функционал пригодится...

Comment: У меня вполне конкретный и простой вопрос - синтаксис тестирования конструктора на живом примере. Мой класс - неудобный? Ладно, напишите ответ на примере абстрактного, удобного класса. Если вы знаете ответ, то почему бы его просто не написать?

Comment: @qtm У меня в ответе 4 варианта написания теста. Если вы не можете по ним написать код, то вы не знаете или PHP, или PHPUnit, или и то, и другое. Конструктор — функция, которая создаёт экземпляр. Почему она вообще должна тестироваться как-то по особому?

Comment: Да, если человек задает вопрос по PHPUnit, это внезапно означает, что он не знает PHPUnit. Собственно, поэтому он и задает вопрос, логично? Оправдываться почему именно у меня возник такой вопрос не вижу смысла. Возник - я спросил. Точка. Но за ответ спасибо, он довольно обстоятельный и кое-что нового я из него почерпнул.

Comment: @qtm Я указал "ключевые слова", которые позволят вам воспользоваться поиском и прочитать полноценную иснструкцию по использованию. Я не привёл примеров с ними, потому что в других фреймворках для тестирования от этих способов наоборот избавляются. Ну а два примера в конце тривиально разворачиваются в реальный код, если вы написали хотя бы один тест на PHPUnit, хотя легенда не повредила бы, пожалуй.